# Jquery fadein/out on dynamic text

Tags: jquery

I am trying to loop through an array and for each, fade out a textfield, populate it and then fade it back in.

I have no idea why this may not be working.

Everything works fine until I add the fadeout.

My jQuery is:

```
for (var i = 0; i < textarr.length; i++) {

    //$('#text' + i).html(textarr[i]); //this works with no fade

    $('#text' + i).fadeOut(function() {
        $(this).html(textarr[i]).fadeIn();
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DKYN9/5/ < fiddle ... youll see what i mean if you comment the fade code and uncomment the line above....Thanks guys

Comment: Could you please provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: Edited with Fiddle, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that after your fadeout is complete `i` is set to 3.
So you have to add a closure:

```
var textarr = new Array();
textarr[0] = "Hello, my name is Barry.";
textarr[1] = "I am a designer in Tokyo";
textarr[2] = "I like stuff.";
changetolang = "jp";

for (var i = 0; i < textarr.length; i++) {
    (function (index) {
        $('#text' + index).fadeOut("slow", function () {
            $(this).html(textarr[index]).fadeIn();
        });
    }(i));
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DKYN9/9/

Another approach would be to return a function with the right scope:

```
var textarr = new Array();
textarr[0] = "Hello, my name is Barry.";
textarr[1] = "I am a designer in Tokyo";
textarr[2] = "I like stuff.";

function fadeIn(i) {
 return function () {
   $(this).html(textarr[i]).fadeIn();
 };  
}

for (var i = 0; i < textarr.length; i++) {
    $('#text' + i).fadeOut("slow", fadeIn(i));
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DKYN9/12/

Comment: That second one is slick. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this updated fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/DKYN9/8/

I changed it to fade in and out the text

```
var curIndex = 0;
$(document).ready(AddText);
function AddText(){    
    if(curIndex >= textarr.length) return;
    $('#text0').fadeOut("slow", function () {
        $(this).html(textarr[curIndex]).fadeIn("slow", function(){            
            curIndex++; 
            AddText();
        });
    });    
}
```

Comment: No go - Edited with Fiddle above. Sorry about that.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but I updated your fiddle

Comment: Apologies Javalsu, maybe I didn't explain properly. See below. Thanks for the help though.